# Compare and loop through an array to find which element has the lower melting point

Tags: java, arrays

After I run the method, it just loops through and prints the entire array and the contents in that index.

Wondering what I am doing wrong and how to make it only print out the array information that is the lowest melting point.

```
public void choiceFive() {
        double smaller = elementArray[0].getMeltingPoint();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            if(elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint() < smaller){
                smaller = elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint();
            }
            System.out.println(smaller);
        }


    }
```

Comment: what is `count` here?

Comment: There's a lot of code missing here. E.g. where does the variable `count` come from and how is it initialized. I guess thats where the error comes from

Comment: count is just to there because it holds the exact number of objects in the array rather than always reading the entire array length
And i guess to be more clear on my question I am trying to loop through and compare which is the lowest melting point along with printing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an `Element` class with name, meltingPoint, and some other properties and you want to find the lowest melting point of an `elementArray`.

### Get lowest melting point:

I implemented a method which returns the `LowestMeltingPoint` element:

1. If elementArray is `null` or it's `empty` return **null**.
2. Set the first element as currentLowestMeltingPoint (because **it is** so far).
3. Loop through the array using [forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (which is pretty more clean) and check if the element melt point is lower than the current. If it's **true**: set the element to `currentLowestMeltingPoint`, otherwise keep the iteration.

Note: It will also print the current lowest with informational purposes.

### Element Class:

```
public class Element
{
    private String name;
    private double meltingPoint;

    public Element ( String name , double meltingPoint )
    {
        super ( );
        this.name = name;
        this.meltingPoint = meltingPoint;
    }

    public String getName ( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getMeltingPoint ( )
    {
        return meltingPoint;
    }

    public void setMeltingPoint ( double meltingPoint )
    {
        this.meltingPoint = meltingPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Element [name=" + name + ", meltingPoint=" + meltingPoint + "]";
    }

}
```

### Main Program:

```
public class MainProgram
{
    /**
     * Main method to test getLowestMeltingPoint method
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        Element helium = new Element ( "Helium" , -272 );
        Element radon = new Element ( "Radon" , -71 );
        Element mercury = new Element ( "Mercury" , -39 );
        Element sulfur = new Element ( "Sulfur" , 113 );
        Element polonium = new Element ( "Polonium" , 254 );

        Element[] elementArray = {mercury, sulfur, radon, polonium, helium};

        Element lowestMeltingPointE = getLowestMeltingPoint ( elementArray );

        System.out.println ( "----------------------------------------------" );
        System.out.println ( "My lowest melting point is: " + lowestMeltingPointE.getName ( ));
        System.out.println ( "Its melting point is: " + lowestMeltingPointE.getMeltingPoint ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "element toString: " + lowestMeltingPointE.toString ( ) );

    }
    /**
     * this method finds the lowest melting point element
     * @param elementArray, which is the element array you want to compare
     * @return element with lowest point or null if array is null or empty
     */

    public static Element getLowestMeltingPoint( Element[]  elementArray)
    {
        Element currentLowest;

        if( elementArray == null || elementArray.length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            currentLowest = elementArray[0];
        }

        for ( Element element : elementArray)
        {
            if ( element.getMeltingPoint ( ) < currentLowest.getMeltingPoint ( ) )
            {
                currentLowest = element;
            }
            System.out.println ( "Current lowest: " + currentLowest.toString ( ) );
        }

        return currentLowest;
    }

}
```

Note: The method is static. If you don't know what it is check: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

### Output:

```
Current lowest: Element [name=Mercury, meltingPoint=-39.0]
Current lowest: Element [name=Mercury, meltingPoint=-39.0]
Current lowest: Element [name=Radon, meltingPoint=-71.0]
Current lowest: Element [name=Radon, meltingPoint=-71.0]
Current lowest: Element [name=Helium, meltingPoint=-272.0]
----------------------------------------------
My lowest melting point is: Helium
Its melting point is: -272.0
element toString: Element [name=Helium, meltingPoint=-272.0]
```

I just wanted to give you the full answer, because there are a lot of resources out there and when i was starting on Java i wasn't aware of.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to move `System.out.println(smaller);` outside the `for` loop. Otherwise you keep printing it.

Answer (score 0):

move the print into the if block

```
        if(elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint() < smaller){
            smaller = elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint();
            System.out.println(smaller);
        }
```

or after processing has completed

```
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint() < smaller){
            smaller = elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint();
        }
  }
  System.out.println(smaller);
```

Comment: He wants the lowest melting point. Not the one that is smaller than the ones before.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++)
```

and move the print statement outside the loop in order to print the lowest melting point amongst all.

```
for(int i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
     if(elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint() < smaller){
         smaller = elementArray[i].getMeltingPoint();
     }
}
System.out.println(smaller);
```